# How to convert to multithreading subprocess

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a method in my python (2.7.6) code that I am looking to use multithreading subprocess on by following the advice given in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316799/44286)

This is how the code is currently:

```
return self.capi(roi_rgb,"",False)
```

This is how I converted it:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)
result = ""
r = pool.map_async(self.capi(roi_rgb,"",False), callback=result)
r.wait()
return result
```

but I'm getting errors with the above on the call to `pool.map_async`

```
TypeError: map_async() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Please add the specific errors to your post.

Comment: @ChrisP `TypeError: map_async() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Your call to `map_async` looks odd; does `self.capi` return a function? [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async) suggests the first argument is a function, followed by an iterable, and that `callback` should be a callable that accepts a single argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html you need to give at least 2 positional arguments where as you gave it one positional and one keyword argument. (The third implicit arg is self)

So you need to pass the method a function and an iterable along with the callback.

P.s.that is a pretty useless error message isn't it?